# Feller - Question on two throws of three dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am stuck at the following question.

> What is the probability that two throws with three dice each will show the same configuration if (a) the dice are distinguishable (b) they are not.

*Solution.*

(a) $P(\text{Two throws of three dice s.t. each show the same configuration})=6^{3}/6^{6}=1/216$.

(b)Firstly from the second set of throws, the $3$ dies with the same face value as the first ones can be chosen in $3!=6$ ways.

Place $r=3$ dies in $n=6$ cells, such that order does not matter with repetition, can be done in ${{3+6-1}\choose{3}}={8\choose 3}=56$

${\displaystyle P(\text{Two throws of three indistinguishable dice show the same configuration})=\frac{56\times6}{6^{6}}}$

However, my answer to the second part of the problem is incorrect. Could someone help me think correctly about the problem.

Comment: 2 throw of 3 dice is equals to one throw of 6 dice. You want same number on all six dice?

Comment: My understanding is, the problem asks for the probability of getting the same configuration - for e.g. if the first throw results in (5,6,6), what is the likelihood that the second throw also results in, perhaps (6,5,6)?

Comment: You mean if in first throw we have (1,2,3) then in next throw we have exact (1,2,3) same pattern.

Comment: after the first throw, the probability of then getting the same configuration is effected by the first configuration - if you first get 6-6-6 then there is only a 1/216 of getting that again.  Therefore you can calculate the prob of getting 3 of a kind, 2 of a kind , or 3 unique  - then multiply by the prob of repeating that - the chaces of repeating is different for each initial roll type

Comment: 1-2-3 is more likely to be repeated than 6-6-6  - can you see why?  Then can you use this to calculate the probability?  (this is in the indistinguishable case)

Comment: what you've got wrong in b) is that if you roll 6-6-6 then you have only 1 way of doing this again, but if you roll 1-2-3 then you have [how many?] ways of doing this again.

Comment: @Cato, when all three faces are distinct, the probability of rolling an ace, deuce and trey again are $6/216$.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh, in the next throw I must have (1,2,3) in any order, is what I understand.

Comment: @Cato, thanks for leading me in the right direction! Cheers. :)

Comment: @quasar - cool!

Answer (score 4):

(b)

Three distinct faces :

$$P(\text{getting the same configuration}) = \frac{(6\cdot5\cdot4)\times(3\cdot2\cdot1)}{6^6}$$

One repetition:

$$P(\text{getting the same configuration}) = \frac{{3\choose2}(6\cdot5)\times{3\choose2}}{6^6}$$

Two repetitions:

$$P(\text{getting the same configuration}) = \frac{6}{6^6}$$

Thus, the required probability is,

$$P(\text{getting the same configuration}) = \frac{996}{6^6}$$

Answer (score 3):

Simulation: Two successive throws of three fair dice with faces 1 through 6. Probability of same three faces showing: (a) if dice are indistinguishable,
(b) distinguishable.

In the distinguishable case, it may help to imagine the dice are colored
red, green, and blue, respectively. The probability is pretty clearly
$1/6^3 =  0.00462963.$ In simulating for the indistinguishable dice, we sort the 
outcomes before comparison because color does not matter.

```
m = 10^6;  same.i = same.d = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  roll.1 = sample(1:6, 3, repl=T)
  roll.2 = sample(1:6, 3, repl=T)
  same.d[i] = sum(roll.1==roll.2)
  same.i[i] = sum(sort(roll.1)==sort(roll.2)) }
mean(same.d==3);  mean(same.i==3)
## 0.004632
## 0.021579
```

With a million iterations, probabilities should be accurate to 
three places (a little more for very small probabilities), so
the first simulated answer is consistent with $1/63.$ And, the
second answer is consistent with with @Quasar's $996/6^6 = 0.02134774.$ (+1)

For a little more detail, my `same.d` and `same.i` are numbers
of faces that agree for distinguishable and indistinguishable dice, respectively.
here are the histograms of their respective distributions.
(The probabilities mainly at issue here are the ones for 3 matches.)

[image]

Comment: I'm getting my hands wet at R, it's a lot of fun to simulate these games and see astonishing results. I liked your sort() trick in the indistinguishable case.

Comment: I see you are fairly new to this site, and welcome. If you will do a search on my user number, you will see that I have posted a _lot_ of R simulations (too many for the tastes of some users, I suppose). These tend to use 'for loops' which is not the greatest style in R (and they don't run as fast as they might), but some of the more sophisticated object oriented R structures would not be as easy for non-R users to understand. (So 'steal' whatever of my tricks you like, but try to develop a more sophisticated style than I feel comfortable using here.)

Comment: @BruceET,  Your R programming is good . But where did you get $\frac{1}{63}$.Answer to the first question where distinguishable dice are used is $\frac{1}{216}$.

Comment: It's $1/6^3 = 1/216.$ In R, `1/6^3` returns 0.00462963, `6^3` returns 216
and `1/216` returns 0.00462963.